# How to edit this mySQL to show results per day?

Tags: mysql

What I aim: to show the hashCount for every day starting from 2016-03-28 to 2016-03-30

So the result shall be like this:

```
300 - 2016-03-28
400 - 2016-03-29
500 - 2016-03-30
```

However I only get the result of

```
300 - 2016-03-28
```

Question: How can I fix this?

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT v.`hash` ) hashCount, DATE( v.`timestamp` ) AS views
FROM audience v
INNER JOIN behaviour b ON v.`hash` = b.`hash` 
WHERE v.`timestamp` 
BETWEEN  '2016-03-28 00:00:00'
AND  '2016-03-28 23:59:59'
AND b.`timestamp` 
BETWEEN  '2016-03-29 00:00:00'
AND  '2016-03-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY views
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `where` condition restricts the range to on date `2016-03-28` only:

```
WHERE v.`timestamp` 
BETWEEN  '2016-03-28 00:00:00'
AND  '2016-03-28 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Hm...how to group them by the second date range?

Comment: Thank you. A last question... Which column should I Index? timestamp or hash? I want to improve the performance

Comment: I am not quite sure. I will index on b.`timestamp`. You can just have a try.